# How to optimize image size in mobile development?

Tags: image, mobile, flutter, image-formats

I am developing a mobile app on flutter. The app will use about 10 thousand images that are loaded from server and cached. Every image now has about 600x400 resolution, jpeg extension, and size about 100Kb. So the total size will be about 1Gb and I have the following questions:

1) Is there a way to reduce the total size? What image format should I use? Should I compress it on server side and decompress in app if images are loaded one by one?

2) What is the best way to choose image resolution so that the app looks good on both the phone and the tablet?

Answer (score 0):

I won't advice you putting a lot of tasks onto the server side.

The server should be doing the **fetching** stuffs,

I would suggest you to

- Enforce compressions on the client which uploads the image to the server
- Pass the images to a third party compressor before they reach your mobile client

The images are of jpeg format, these are easily resized.

[This site](http://www.jpeg-optimizer.com/) can help you with the compression..

But I still emphasize you to do it yourself on the client who uploads the image